# How do I sculpt indentations on a mesh object?

Tags: animation, sculpting

I'm trying to sculpt a primitive face out of a sphere, but when I use any type of sculpting tool, the entire sphere remains intact, as if there were two layers, one a perfect sphere that never changes and one I can edit. I'm able to pull material away from the sphere just not into it. I have tried this with blank spheres, yet even then, nothing happens. I didn't bother attaching a picture because it wouldn't show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i am everything but a sculpter, but the basics are: use enough subdivisions and increase strength to "see something":

1. create UV sphere
2. tab to edit mode -> right click, subdivide
3. change to sculpting
4. increase strength to 3 and choose "draw sharp"
5. enjoy result

[image]